# PHP didn't show text from table MySQL for specific user

Tags: php, mysql

i tried to make some changes for my page.
So,i want to show for users a specific coins what are in the table.(Table are created)
But,when i try to doing this didn't work(didn't show) if i want for the username.
Work only without verification for user id/name.

My code:

```
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $_GET["id"];
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

        echo "<dt>Coins:</dt><dd>" . $row["coins"] . "</dd>";

    }
```

I tried to `$_GET["id"]` with `["username"]`.But also didn't work (Verification for session is like this: `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))`

Somebody know why didn't work?

Comment: Did you get an error or simply no output?  By the way, you should seriously look into using parameterized queries, to avoid SQL injection and other unsavory things.

Comment: Hi,i don't have any error.Simply no output

Comment: When you run the raw query on MySQL do you get any output?

Comment: Why do you assume your query executes correctly?

Comment: No,i don't have any output.

Comment: No output with your query yet you expect an output while using it in php? Seriously?

Comment: I activated errors to my website,and,i got this: Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/admin/web/mrtunne.tk/public_html/test/index.php on line 14

Comment: Show the output of query - var_dump($strSQL) and also var_dump($rs).

Answer (score 0):

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
```

Comment: In mysql, integers don't need quotes. Secondly, who says `$_GET['id']` is set?

Comment: i think he is ending the query before $_GET['id'] and yes you are right may b $_GET['id'] is not set

Comment: So I ask again, why does he assume his query executes correctly?

Comment: well print_r the query first